# Shifting single row data to single column

Tags: excel, matlab

I am trying to store the cell array `val` as a Excel file (xls). This cell array has a structure of 1 x 62328.

```
val=

Column 1 through 4

{'data1'}   {'data2'}   {'data3'}

Column 5 through 8

{'data4'}   {'data5'}   {'data5'}

and so on up to 62328 columns.
```

As Excel doesn't support this large amount of columns, so how do I write the data into a single column instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can transpose a cell array by simply adding `.'` after it.

When you then write your cell array down to a xls file just insert `val.'` instead of `val`.